# Hashing a string value to the interval [0; 1]

Tags: java, scala

I need to make hashing of `pk` values (e.g. `1289359`, `345623p`, etc.) to the interval [0; 1]. The mapping should be deterministic in order to get the same result every time I run the code (I don't want to use seed numbers). 
For example, the result of mapping `1289359` might be `0.35` (just an example).
How can I do it? Any hint would be highly appreciated.
It is preferable that the solution is given in Scala, but it might be also in Java.

UPDATE:

Sorry for not posting my code sample that I tried as a possible solution:

```
String myString = "345623p";
double value = Double.parseDouble(myString);
```

I don't know how to map it to the exact interval [0; 1].

Comment: Should the result of your hash be a double?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, it should be double.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I tried simply this solution: `double value = Double.parseDouble(myString);`. But how can I specify the interval [0; 1]?

Comment: @f1sh: It's the limitation. I don't see any problem with that. See my comment for Yuval Itzchakov. I obviously tried things.

Comment: @Dinosaurius Add your attempt to the question.

Comment: that is just for parsing a String to double. What approaches have you tried to get it to your interval range ? And what are your dis-satisfactions or problems with your approach ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: But this is my question. If I knew the answer, I would not ask.

Comment: You know... 1 approach is to divide your double by `Double.MaxValue` which will always give you [0,1] range.... but will that be fine... what do you want ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: Ok, I see. I would prefer the uniform distribution. For example, if I totally have 10,000 possible values of `pk`, then they should be uniformly distributed over the interval [0; 1].

Comment: Well... that really won't be possible. "Uniform" distribution is not that simple to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are vague, but I think this satisfies them.

```
val r = scala.util.Random

val pks = List("1289359", "345623p")

val hashes = pks.map { pk =>
  r.setSeed(pk.hashCode())
  (pk, r.nextDouble())
}
```

`List((1289359,0.36724077736416283), (345623p,0.243112317891797))`

Note that there are some unexpected results of this approach. If the keys are very close (e.g. differ by the last char) then the hashes will also be very close, due to how scala's Random.nextDouble works.
`List((1234560,0.40817931760409776), (1234561,0.4084480629207127), (1234562,0.4083584960496689), (1234563,0.41077718899804194))`

Comment: A nice attempt without knowing the "requirements".

Comment: Thanks, Tom. It's helpful.

Comment: @Dinosaurius see my edit regarding a concern I just thought of.

Comment: I found using `random` as a hash function ugly. Perhaps using something from `scala.util.hashing` would be more appropriate?